# Is there a filesystem that writes everything to nothing?

Tags: filesystem

The user case is that a program writes files which I do not want to preserve to a dedicated folder. So is there a filesystem that drops write request but returns OK/done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write to `/dev/null`, but you might need root permissions (not sure about that, just try). You can also delete files by moving them there, e.g. `mv justanytrash.txt /dev/null`

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I expected. The "program" is not maintained by me. Thus I cannot change its writing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to /dev/null will not work if the program tries to create a file and write to it. That is not something that you can do in /dev/null.

Perhaps the next best thing would be to create a temporary file system in memory. Then the files will be written, but will be discarded when the system is shutdown, or when the temporary file system is unmounted.

Steps to take:

1. Create a mount point for the temporary file system:

`sudo mkdir /mnt/tmpfs`

2. Create and mount a temporary memory filesystem of, say, 100 Mb:

`sudo mount -osize=100m tmpfs /mnt/tmpfs -t tmpfs`

3. Create a symbolic link from the file system to the dedicated folder:

`sudo ln -s /mnt/tmpfs /path/to/dedicated/folder`

Now the files will be written to /mnt/tmpfs, and they will be gone when you do

`sudo umount  /mnt/tmpfs`